# Is it possible to use for an absolute positioned element the calc() function?

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to use for an absolute positioned element the calc() function?
I get the warning "Invalid property value" in the firefox browser, when using the calc function for the `top` property as seen below.

```
 .absolute {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: calc(50% + progressBarHeight);
    top: -webkit-calc(50% + progressBarHeight); // progressBarHeight is a sass variable
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

Comment: Yes it is possible... What is the `progressBarHeight` coming from and what is its length of measurement type, perhaps you should add that bit of code to your question.

Comment: You should use something like top: `calc(50% + #{$progressBarHeight});` to use the value of the variable. sass will replace the value of the variable so the variable itself is not available in css files. if you are using it in .css file it it is not a defined variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use `calc` for `top/bottom/left/right`. Check the below snippet.

If your sass variable `progressBarHeight` is in the format of `20px`. You can use directly Or try as @Erfan mentioned `calc(50% + #{$progressBarHeight});`

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 20px;
  left: calc(50% - 20px)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hi</span>
</div>
```